# Jtest with gradle builds

Tags: gradle, jtest

We are using Parasoft Jtest to generate the Static Analysis reports for Java codes by using Jtestcli for Ant and Maven builds. Now we have a requirement to do the same for Gradle builds.

Did not find any direct links to same.

Hence needed help on, How to use/run Jtest with gradle builds to generate Static Analysis reports for Java code?

Comment: Which version do you use?